# directive name as tag is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to create a simple custom directive and i have came across this issue.
When i specify the directive as `<div my-info></div>`in my html file, it is working but when i specify as `<my-info></my-info>`, it is not working.

My app.js file

```
app.directive('myInfo', function () {
return {
       template:"<h3>My info directive</h3>" };});
```

My html file

```
<body ng-app="app">
 <div ng-controller="emp">
    <div my-info></div> <!-- This is working-->
   <my-info></my-info> <!-- This is not working -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.directive('myInfo', function () {
    return {
       restrict: 'EA', // can be applied as element or attribute
       template:"<h3>My info directive</h3>" 
    };
});
```

By default directives can only be applied as attributes (A). Make sure you add `restrict` field and specify it can be applied as element as well.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('myInfo', function () {
    return {
       restrict: 'EA',
       template:"<h3>My info directive</h3>"
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
 <div>
    <div my-info></div>
    <my-info></my-info>
 </div>
</div>
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive for more information

Comment: When you create a directive, it is restricted to attribute and elements only by default. In order to create directives that are triggered by class name/comment, you need to use the restrict option.

Comment: @arunkumartalla was you comment meant for this post?

Comment: no @Chanthu  for this `By default directives can only be applied as attributes (A). `

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
app.directive('myInfo', function () {   
    return {
           restrict: 'E',
           template:"<h3>My info directive</h3>" };});
```

[From angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

The restrict option is typically set to:

'A' - only matches attribute name
'E' - only matches element name
'C' - only matches class name
'M' - only matches comment

You can also combine it like   `restrict: 'EA'`

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

  </head>
 <body ng-app="app">
 <div ng-controller="emp">
    <div my-info></div> <!-- This is working-->
   <my-info></my-info> <!-- This is working -->
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('emp', function() {

}).directive('myInfo', function () {
return {
       template:"<h3>My info directive</h3>"
    };
});
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Actually when you are working with angular directive

```
app.directive('myInfo', function () {   
    return {
           restrict: 'E',
           template:"<h3>My info directive</h3>" 
};
});
```

Above code will make retrict your directive for element only,If you want to play with attribute you need to add **"retrict:A"**, if both **"retrict:EA"**

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke a directive by using:

> - Attribute (A) `<div my-info></div>`
> - Element (E) `<my-info></my-info>`
> - Class (C) `<div class="my-info"></div>`
> - Comment (M) `<!-- directive: my-info -->`

Add a restrict property in the directive